# Php - Symfony2 - Rest api - huge data

Tags: php, multithreading, api, rest, symfony

I have a quite conceptual question about working with APIs which handle huge amount of data.

I have two web applications running:

- System A, which acts like a source
- System B, which is the target system

both use RESTful API to communicate with each other.

Now it comes to sending huge amounts of data (about 1 million rows) from A to B.

My concept is to select all data from database and i.e. create one main-array with 1 million subarrays. Next iterate through the main-array to get every single row and send this specific row as Post-Request to System B.

Code Sample:

```
$data = $sql-to-get-all-data;
$mainArray = $data->fetchAll();

foreach ($mainArray as $subArray) {

    $row = $subArray;

    // create post request and send $row to System B

}
```

Next I would need to check if the row already exists in System B. If it does, send an Update-Request instead of a Post-Request.
Also ... if there is a row which exists in System B, but does not exist in System A, it should be removed from System A.

My question is:

Is this the right way to go with?
Should I think about concepts like parallel processing / multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

You should use offset and limit in your db query. Storing entire dataset in a PHP array is a really bad idea.

You can send subsets in batches and return id lists (added/updated/removed) within response.

Comment: thanks for answer, first: how can i get all data at the end if i use offset and limit? second: i did not understand how to remove rows from System B if they are not present in System A ?

Comment: First:
You have to specify your limit, and execute queries in a loop.
First for offset 0, and limit, next for offset 0+limit+1 and limit, etc.
Second: You can just execute a delete query where ids are not in your id list.

It's always great to give us more info about your business logic. Maybe we can simplify your problem.